# python word counter display duplicates only

Tags: python, counter, cpu-word

can some one help me im trying to do counter in python but i dont want results if they are not duplicated

```
 from collections import Counter
import collections

with open('test.txt') as myFile:
    array =[]
    for word in myFile:
        #convert all to lowercase
        word_lower = word.lower()

        #escape punctuation
        import string
        for row in string.punctuation:
            word_lower = word_lower.replace(row,"")
        array.append(word_lower)

        a = collections.Counter(array)

    print a
```

myfile looks like
test

john

mike

test

kim

kim

but my output is now showing everything, i want upgrade display only if name is shown multiple times

Answer (score 2):

You need to filter after you have used the Counter dict to get your word count, you can map `str.split` on  the file object, `chain` the elements together rstripping the punctuation away and only keep the keys from the `Counter` dict that have a value > 1:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain
from string import punctuation

with open('test.txt') as f:
    cn = Counter(w.lower().rstrip(punctuation) 
                 for w in chain.from_iterable(map(str.split,f)))
    # if v > 1 the word appeared at least twice
    print [w for w,v in cn.items() if v > 1]
```

It does not matter how many words you have per line, splitting will remove the newlines etc.. and chaining will chain all the words allowing you to call `rstrip` to remove the punctuation from each.

If you want to remove punctuation from anywhere then just `str.translate` it:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain
from string import punctuation

with open('test.txt') as f:
    cn = Counter(w.lower().translate(None, punctuation) 
                 for w in chain.from_iterable(map(str.split,f)))
    print [w for w,v in cn.items() if v > 1]
```

`w.translate(None, punctuation)` will make `foo's` into `foos`, where rsrip would leave `foo's` as is, you will have to  decide which is more suitable.

If you want a dict as output just change the list comp:

```
out = {w:v for w,v in cn.items() if v > 1}
```

Using either `str.translate` or `str.rstrip(punctuation)` is going to be a lot more efficient than   `for row in string.punctuation...` and calling replace every time

Comment: There's plenty of those going around

Answer (score 0):

```
    import collections

    with open('data.csv') as myFile:
        lines = myFile.read().lower().splitlines()
        dict = collections.Counter(lines)

    print(dict)

>>> Counter({'kim': 2, 'mike': 1, 'john': 1, 'test': 1})
```

You're code is missing some major concepts regarding reading a file and `Counter`.

`Counter` takes a list and count the number of occurances. So when you read from the file you'll need to add it to a list shown in line 5 of the script above.

Now you have a `collections.Counter` class with the names as `keys` and the count as `values`. You can take those and output the ones whose values are greater than 2.

For the latter part you can do:

```
filtered_dict = {k:v for (k,v) in array.items() if array[k] >= 2}
>>> {'kim': 2}
```

Comment: Not mine but you don't handle any punctuation, there is also no need to create two full copies of the data in memory, you actually don't need to store all the lines at all

Comment: I see yours got offset at least

Comment: I agree with the double data. From the sample data it didn't seem there's need for punctuation, but seeing the original example I see why

Comment: I imagine the real data has punctuation

Answer (score 0):

i manage to do it on my own
here's how

```
import collections
import string
with open('test.txt') as myFile:
    array =[]
    for word in myFile:
        # convert all to lowercase
        word_lower = word.lower()
        # skip empty rows in file
        if word_lower != "\n":
            # escape punctuation
            for char in string.punctuation:
                word_lower = word_lower.replace(char,"")
                # styling   for output in same row
                word_lower = word_lower.replace("\n","")
            # save result in array
            array.append(word_lower)

        # counter array
        a = collections.Counter(array)
for item in a:
    if a[item] >1:
        print item, a[item]
```